# Red lines coming up after strings in SublimeREPL (python)?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

In writing a simple python application, I'm printing out some strings to the console in SublimeREPL (for python), using Python 2.7.8 and Sublime 3, 64 bit for Windows 8.1. However, I'm getting some very annoying red lines after each of the strings that I'm printing. Does someone know why this is happening?

[image: Picture of the red lines]

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apostrophe `'` character is causing Sublime's syntax highlighting engine to think that you're beginning a single-quoted string. Since ending a line with a string "open" is an error, it is being highlighted with the reddish `invalid.illegal` scope in your color scheme. It's nothing to worry about, it's just something you'll see happen with SublimeREPL when you have non-closing quotes on a line.

To verify this is the case, try opening a new file in Sublime, setting the syntax to Python, and pasting in the following code:

```
"This is a valid string"
"This is also valid even though it has a single quote ' char"
"This string is not valid
"""This string is valid, and doesn't have the red line
even though it has a newline, as it's triple-quoted"""
```

The middle (invalid Python syntax) line will have the red stripe from the end of the word `valid` to the right side of the window. The others won't.

[image]

Comment: So... how can I can get rid of it?