# How to get rid of Sublime Text's mistaken error highlighting when using SublimeREPL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

When using the ' character as an apostrophe, building python code using SublimeREPL causes sublime text to mistake that apostrophe for a single quote and create annoying red highlights.

For example, this code:

```
    hnumber = int(input("How many players are there? "))
           h_inc = 0
    while h_inc < hnumber:
        print(f"\n Player {h_inc + 1}'s hand:")
        print(deck1.draw())
        h_inc += 1
```

Produces this unpleasant result:
[image]

I want to get rid of these red bars. How do I do that without disabling the syntax highlighting function completely? Or is my best course of action to create a toggle hotkey for the red bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer by Aqueum in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692051/is-it-possible-to-disable-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-repl-tabs)

Go to
Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - User

(If your 'Settings - User' is empty, first copy in the contents of 'Settings - Default')

under "repl_view_settings": add:

```
,
    "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
```

so mine is now:

```
// standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
// this has to be customized as a whole dictionary
"repl_view_settings": {
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "auto_indent": false,
    "smart_indent": false,
    "spell_check": false,
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false,
    "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
},
```